# Ios: in app purchase dialog not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store

I'm currently developing an ios app that has an in app purchase.

When ever i add an SKPayment into the payment queue nothing happens.

```
    public func buyProduct(product: SKProduct) {
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self);

    print("buy \(product.productIdentifier)");
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(SKPayment(product: product));
}
```

I have checked everything is not null and everything is valid, but i literally press the buy button on my app and nothing appears, no prompt to ask me if i want to buy the product.

There are no errors or warnings inside the console, literally nothing happens.

The transactionState seems to be updating but there doesn't seem to be any useful information as to why the prompt isnt appearing.

```
     public func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    for transaction in transactions {
        print(transaction.transactionIdentifier);
        print(transaction.transactionState);
        print(transaction.originalTransaction)
        print(transaction.error);
    }


}
```

outputs (After one tap)

```
buy com.innovationsoft.top10.unlock_cat_8

nil

SKPaymentTransactionState

nil

nil
```

P.S when i run on simulator I get a prompt to sign in to iTunes, however on any physical device nothing happens.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you add `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)` in your app delegate?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26677736/3953581

Comment: Hi, I have modified the post to include what i've tried, i've added it right before adding to the payment queue just to be safe, still no luck.

Comment: Add it to your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in appDelegate and try.

Comment: Look into setting up a sandbox account. Unless you are using TestFlight you need one of those for anything to happen re IAPs

Comment: Hi, I have updated into app delegate and also added some output, still no luck, see the updated post :) thank you.

Comment: I am also using a sandbox account, surely if i wasnt signed in anyway it would still appear asking me to sign in ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was some kind of ios bug.

I restarted my device and everything is working now.

-_-